# Simple script with Error in output - Ruby language

Tags: ruby

I'm starting in ruby language and I have the following problem:
"Look at the script below and see the output he's giving me (meaningless to me). I do not know if there are any mistakes in writing but I do not think so. Anyone have any suggestions for what's going on?"
Note: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

```
class Contagem
    def initialize(x,y)
        @variavel1 = x
        @variavel2 = y
    end

    def teste1
        return @variavel1
    end

    def teste2
        return @variavel2
    end
end

valor1 = 1
valor2 = 2

valores = Contagem.new(valor1,valor2)
puts valores
```

**Output:**

```
#<Contagem:0x0000000190c148>
```

Comment: I literally have no idea what is being asked here. But the code looks okey-ish.

Comment: i think hes trying to get us to debug his code or ask why the output is what it is

Comment: In this example, you just asking to output the class by `puts valores
 `. So you can do `puts valores.as_json` to access to the variable inside your class or `valores. teste1` to get the value of your  `@variavel1`

Comment: this is stuff he could just google lol or maybe actually look at ruby docs

Comment: Snoobie, put valores.as_json did not help. However, values.test1 came to the result I wanted. Thank you very much.

Sergio Tulentsev, thanks for the feedback.

L_Church, thanks for the debug tip. I'm going to study about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing the following:

```
valores = Contagem.new(valor1,valor2)
puts valores
```

You ask Ruby to print your Object valores which gives you:

```
#<Contagem:0x0000000190c148>
```

You can see more details by doing:

```
puts valores.inspect
```

But if you want to print the value, just call the functions you made:

```
puts valores.teste1
puts valores.teste2
```

Comment: Makushimaru, thank you very much. I enjoyed learning about .inspect. In addition, valores.test1 and valores.teste2 worked perfectly, it was this result that I wanted.

Comment: No problem ! Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

The output you see is not an error but an internal representation of the object in ruby.

To improve the output you could define the `to_s` instance method. In this method you build and return a string that has an output to your liking. E.g.:

```
class Contagem
  def to_s
    sprintf("variavel1: %d, variavel2: %d", @variavel1, @variavel2) 
  end
end
```

This is assuming that @variavel1 and @variavel2 are ints.

Comment: mbuechmann, thank you very much for the class. This tip is perfect.

Comment: As @Makushimaru pointed out the `inspect` method is handy, too.